# No idea how to prove $f$ is Lebesgue integrable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\} \in L(I)$ and $\{f_n\} \geq 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that

1. $f_n \rightarrow f$ is pointwise convergent almost everywhere in $I$
2. There exists $A > 0$ such that $\int_{I} f_n \leq A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Prove that $f \in L(I)$ and $\int_{I} f \leq A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fatou's lemma gives $\int_I f = \int_I \liminf_n f_n \le \liminf_n \int_I f_n \le A$.